# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d_{n}(x,y)}{2^{n}}$ is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Could you help me with the following please, I have a question with the following:

If $d_1,d_2,...$ is a succession of metrics in a space $X$ such that $d_{n}(x, y) \leq 1$ for each $x, y \in X$ and each $n$. Prove that the function $d: X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by

$$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d_{n}(x,y)}{2^{n}}$$

is a metric in $X$.

My question in particular is, because it is important or where the hypothesis is applied that $d_{n}(x, y) \leq 1$? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It's important to guarantee the convergence of the sum.

Comment: With this you could get a formula for d?

Comment: It gives you a formula for $d$. You just need to show that $d$ satisfies the properties of a metric.

Comment: @user797616 Wouldn't it be enough for $d_n$ to be bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, we will see that $d(x,y)$ is well-defined: note that
  $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n(x,y)}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}<\infty \textrm{ for all $N \geq 1$,}$$
  which means that $\Big( \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n(x,y)}{2^n} \Big)_{N=1}^\infty$ is bounded above, and hence, converges$^1$.
- Next, we will to verify that $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(y,z)$. But this is also easy: since
  $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n(x,y)}{2^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n(x,z)}{2^n} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n(y,z)}{2^n} \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z) \textrm{ for all $N \geq 1$,}$$
  the set
  $$S = \bigg\{ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{d_n(x,y)}{2^n} :\, N \geq 1 \bigg\}$$
  is bounded above by $d(x,z)+d(y,z)$, and therefore, $d(x,y) = \sup S \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)$. I will leave to you the proof of $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$ (why the other properties in the definition of a metric are redundant?).

---

$^1$ It is also a non-decreasing sequence because $d_n(x,y) \geq 0$.